# Make a tag specific to a certain technology

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

I added a tag for state preservation and restoration, a technique in iOS to save and reload app state (tab number, scroll position, etc). I named the tag [state-restoration](/questions/tagged/state-restoration). There is no main class for this function, it's sprinkled among different classes, so there was no "`UIStatePreservation`" that I could pin the tag to. There is already an "application-state" tag which is used with android, .net and other things, which people have been using to refer to iOS state restoration.

What's the best way to make a tag like this more technology-specific, or should I just leave it as is?

Answer (score 4):

I would think [application-state](/questions/tagged/application-state) to be a sufficiently generic tag that doesn't require further specialization. The fact that you want to restore it is just a small subset of the related functionality - it's not like we also have tags for [array-append](/questions/tagged/array-append), [array-reverse](/questions/tagged/array-reverse), [array-flip](/questions/tagged/array-flip) etc., those all belong under the generic [arrays](/questions/tagged/arrays) category.

Once a tag becomes specific to a single unique operation it doesn't present added value to the contents of the question itself anymore.

Comment: I'm not really trying to differentiate between the general topic of "application state" and it's specific subset "state restoration". In iOS you can save state in a custom way (without any help from the OS, just saving variables to disk manually) or you can use specific methods from the Framework, newly introduced in iOS 6. That's what I want to specify. Currently, finding all questions about the new methods isn't easy. The only way is to search for something like `restorationIdentifier` (an iOS property), but that doesn't encompass everything.